# modal popup not showing on top of another modal popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asmx

### Updated

I am trying to use modal as confirmation prompt on another modal but confirmation modal is not vissible on onclick. Here is the modals properties I set.

### Parent Modal.

I am calling my parent modal in my asmx file and then I am calling my child modal function in an asmx file as well.

```
<div id="ShowDetails" class="popup" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute;" role="dialog">
    <div class="panel panel-green">
        <div class="panel-heading">Parchase Request Details</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class=" col-md-12">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <input id="pdid" style="display: none; width: 90PX; margin: 2px;" type="hidden" />
                    <%--<asp:HiddenField ID="PDId" runat="server" />--%>
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="item" style="display: none; width: 90PX; margin: 2px;" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="quantity" style="display: none; width: 90PX; margin: 2px;" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="eprice" style="display: none; width: 90PX; margin: 2px;" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="make" style="display: none; width: 90PX; margin: 2px;" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="discription" style="display: none; width: 90PX; margin: 2px;" />
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <a id="DoneEditingbtn" role="button" onclick="DoneEditing()" style="color: #72c02c; display: none; width: 100PX; margin: 2px;">Update</a>
                            </td>
                            <td><a id="cancleediting" role="button" onclick="cancleeditingdetail()" style="color: #72c02c; display: none; width: 100PX; margin: 2px;">cancel</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color: #01cc66;">
                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Estimated Price</th>
                                <th>Make</th>
                                <th>Discription</th>
                                <th>Options</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tblgetdetails">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div id="Alert"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="popup-btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">close</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Confirmation Modal.

```
    <div id="ApproveMod" class="popup" style=" z-index:2; position:absolute; left: 50%; width: 40%; border: 10px solid #666;">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <i>Are you sure to Approve this data?</i>
    </div>
    <i id="pheadIdApp"></i>
    <i id="pbdIdApp"></i>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <a class="btn-u btn-u-red" href="#" role='button' style="text-align: center; width: 45%;" onclick="Approve()">Yes </a>
        <button class="btn-u btn-u-green-custom " style="text-align: center; width: 45%;" data-dismiss="modal">NO</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Parent modal is showing properly but when I click on parent modal button which should toggle child modal, is not working, In ASMX I have defined my child modal function on onclick as following.

```
<a role='button' class='form-control' onclick='AppModal(PHId+","+PBDId)'>Approve</a>
```

Here is the child calling approach I used in script.

```
function AppModal(phid,pbdid) {
        $("#pheadIdApp").val(phid);
        $("#pbdIdApp").val(pbdid);
        $("#ApproveMod").modal("show");
    }
```

It should work properly I have used it many times but now I am stuck and have no idea where I might have missed the trick any kind of help is much much apriciated.

Comment: cud u recreate the issue in the code-runner

Comment: Since you mentioned z-index, did you check z-index for ShowDetails?

Comment: Check it now I have given both modal elements and child modal using technique.

Comment: SouXin  parent modal z-index is set zero by default so there not really need to define z-index.

Comment: Looks like you are using bootstrap modal. If this is the case then z-index for bootstrap modal is more then 0. (But if you define it in your code then I'm wrong). I just recently had similar issue. z-index of the parent was overridden. To check it try `$('#ShowDetails').modal('hide')` then your additional menu suppose to be appeared.

Comment: Wait. Your onclick function looks weird.  onclick='AppModal(PHId+","+PBDId)'`  What suppose to mean + after and before parameters? If they are values then placement of the quotation is wrong

Comment: No Its absolutely right and working the thing is I just wrote the main part. here I used html tag in Asmx so you can start your tag with " " and then define properties with the use of ' 'single quoatation.

Comment: this is the main part I want my child modal over parent modal I cant hide it. I am not understanding what am I missing or doing wrong.

Comment: No just launch the statement from console (F12 Chrome). After that Inside your function `function AppModal(phid,pbdid)` place `console.log(phid); console.log(pbdid);` You have to see values in the console.

Comment: values are fatched correctly. The Issue is with modal z-index I suppose.

Comment: Is there any othere way to popup child modal over parent?

Comment: By default z-index in bootstrap > 1040. Set for child 1100 for testing. If it fixes just overwrite bootstrap's z-index in css. BTW try remove z-index from child

Comment: Yeah I suppose that should do the trick let me try. By removing z-index in child will make it default layer which will again get me in trouble.

Comment: It works now I had to change my child modal position to relative in order to show above the parent modal. thanks alot. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120465/discussion-between-imtiaz-and-souxin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Really Funny Yesterday I got an answer to my problem by you which was about the same problem and now I find you stuck here.
Change your child modal position to relative and assign z-index value greater then 1040 which is for default layer.

Comment: Yes you are absolutly right I didnt know much about bootstrap z-index default values thanks.

Comment: position is not an issue it could be relative or absolute depending on your need.